# Hadoop Streaming Job not working in OOzie

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to write a simple map only hadoop streaming job reading data from hdfs and pushing it to vertica.

I have written a shell script as below

```
./vsql -c "copy $TABLE from stdin delimiter E'\t' direct null '\\N';" -U $DBUSER -w $DBPWD -h $DBHOST -p $DBPORT
```

I have created oozie workflow as :

```
 <action name="loadToVertica">
        <map-reduce>
                            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                            <prepare>
                                    <delete path="${nameNode}/user/$USER/output/${exportDataDate}"/>
                            </prepare>
                            <streaming>
                                    <mapper>shell export.sh</mapper>
                            </streaming>
                            <configuration>
                                    <property>
                                            <name>oozie.libpath</name>
                                            <value>${wfsBasePath}/libs</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                            <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                                            <value>${nameNode}/user/$USER$/{exportDataDate}</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                            <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                                            <value>${nameNode}/user/$USER/output/${exportDataDate}</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                            <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
                                            <value>0</value>
                                    </property>
                            </configuration>
                            <file>${wfsBasePath}/libs/${STREAMING_JAR_PATH}#${STREAMING_JAR_PATH}</file>
                            <file>${wfsBasePath}/libs/oozie-sharelib-streaming-4.2.0.2.5.3.0-37.jar#oozie-sharelib-streaming-4.2.0.2.5.3.0-37.jar</file>
                            <file>${wfsBasePath}/scripts/export.sh#export.sh</file>
                            <file>${wfsBasePath}/config/vsql#vsql</file>
                    </map-reduce>
            <ok to="end"/>
           <error to="end"/>
        </action>
```

When i run this the status of job is Failed/Killed without any error message.

Comment: What's about the logs? Try to execute it without Oozie first.

Comment: Without oozie it runs fine. Data is successfully loaded to Vertica @FieryCat

Comment: Sometimes it could be related to a folder permissions. Logs will give an answer: `cd /var/log/oozie/; ls` or `oozie job -oozie $OOZIE_URL -info {job id}`

Comment: Can't find any error in yarn logs @FieryCat

Comment: Then, please, enable them first by following: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Oozie-logs-enable/td-p/36647 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397725/workflow-error-logs-disabled-in-oozie-4-2

Comment: We are on HDP plus logging is enabled. In rest cases i get error messages. The issue seems that sh file is never called because when i echo something, it doesnt show up in logs. @FieryCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding -e in after #!/bin/sh helped me to trace what the actual error is.

After adding -e option in the script there was an error code in the logs.

After this the first line would look like :

```
#!/bin/sh -e
```